# before in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, spark-java

I'm trying to set a before filter without a path to apply to all requests.  In kotlin I'm trying to write:

```
before { req, resp -> 
    // check auth then redirect if not authorized... 
}
```

The compiler says:

> Cannot infer type for this parameter (req & resp).

How should I set a before filter in Kotlin without a route?

Comment: What's the definition of `before`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the path `*` in Spark to match all paths, like this:

```
before("*", { req, res ->
    logger.info("${req.requestMethod().toUpperCase()} ${req.fullUri()} by ${req.ip()} (${req.userAgent()})")
})

// or:

before("*") { req, res -> // ...
```

Comment: Always use the second example when the last parameter of the function is a lambda type.

Comment: @marstran Why? Afaik these are just syntax differences, each resulting in the same bytecode, so it's up to the developer's preference